# Bluetooth connection from Raspberry Pi to Parani SD100- No usable services

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to connect my raspberry Pi to a Parani SD1000 RS232 serial adapter. I have configured the Parani and I can successfully connect to it and retrieve data when using my Macbook. I would like to set up the connection using my raspberry pi. I have a raspberry Pi 3 model b+ 32 bit. I wrote a script that uses Pyserial and created a bind to the bluetooth device via `sudo rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 1`. However, when I use the Raspberry PI OS interface to connect to the bluetooth I get a message that `'Paired successfully, but this device has no services with can be used with the Raspberry Pi` and the connection is aborted.

I've looked for other suggestions and tried updating my software as listed elsewhere. To no avail.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall raspberrypi-sys-mods
sudo systemctl reboot
```

I'm not sure which direction I should be looking. I know the Parani is configured correctly so it must be something on the raspberry. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rfcomm` was [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) back in 2017 by the BlueZ project so I would recommend against using that methodology.

Python3 on Linux supports connecting to a Bluetooth Classic device with a Serial Port Profile (SPP) with its [socket library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

There is more information in the following blog: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

There is also support for SPP within the Bluedot Python library: https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/07/python-bluetooth-rfcomm-client-server.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestions seem to be focused toward the python end of the communication but the problem seems to be pairing the Raspberry Pi to the Parani bluetooth as the connection is instantly aborted due to "no usable services". I cannot find any resources in your links that would help resolve that end of the problem. Or did I miss something? Thanks in advance

Comment: It says in your question that the pairing was successful but it is disconnecting because there is no SPP client running on the RPi. Pairing is only a one time provisioning step and so for subsequent connections there is no need to do the pairing again. I am assuming there is an SPP server running on the Parani so you need to start a client on the RPi that is why I posted the above links.